# How to use added typings in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to learn Typescript, and have set up a basic typescript structure following [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html) tutorial.

I need to add typings to the project now. So I looked around and found [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings). Then I added `JQuery`,`Lodash`, and `D3` using typings. My project structure looks like this:

```
├── dist
│   ├── chart.js
│   ├── greet.js
│   └── main.js
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── ts
│       ├── chart.ts
│       ├── greet.ts
│       └── main.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings
│   ├── globals
│   │   └── jquery
│   │       ├── index.d.ts
│   │       └── typings.json
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   └── modules
│       ├── d3
│       │   ├── index.d.ts
│       │   └── typings.json
│       └── lodash
│           ├── index.d.ts
│           └── typings.json
└── typings.json
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/ts/*.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I add the `*.d.ts` files which I have in `typings` directory in my `main.ts` file and start using jQuery's `$` or D3's `d3`?

I noticed `index.d.ts` file in `typings` which looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/d3/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/lodash/index.d.ts" />
```

So my guess is, I just need to add this file somewhere in my `main.ts` file or in my `tsconfig.json` file(instead of manually adding each `.d.ts` file). Am I right? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript 2 recommends using npm for types. See [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

All you should need is something like:

```
npm install --save @types/lodash @types/d3 @types/jquery
```

and be good to go.

Comment: You do not want them to be development dependencies. Make them dependencies using `save` instead of `save-dev`.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Okay, I modified it to --save as in the article. You might be able to answer this question I created regarding why this is required. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097488/typescript-2-saving-npm-types-typings-with-save-or-save-dev

Comment: I doubt `@types` are used after typescripts are compiled into `js`. So I bet having them as production deps is not necessary.

Comment: @user61382 From the answer to my follow up question, "The problem comes along when you might have dependencies. If you stored your type declarations in your devDependencies, your consumers would not automatically get your type declarations.", It is not necessary, but can be useful for consumers.

Comment: @RationalDev hmmm so that's the case when the interface to your library exposes some types from third party libraries? You probably better to re-export them then. I am a novice to TS but saving types to deps does not seem to be recommended https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/@types.html

Comment: @user61382 See here for the original quote from a TypeScript member: https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81#issuecomment-234051345

Answer (score 4):

You can add it in your tsconfig:

```
"files": [
    "src/ts/*.ts",
    "typings/**/*.ts"
]
```

or just

```
"files": [
    "src/ts/*.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have added the `index.d.ts` file in my `tssconfig.json`. Now how do I get my `.ts` files to recognize `$` and such symbols? Do I have to add/require anything in my `.ts` file?

Comment: I added `import $ from "./jquery";` and also tried `import $ from "jquery";` but get following error: `cannot fine module jquery`