# Saving npm @types typings with --save or --save-dev

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript2.0

TypeScript 2 recommends using npm for types. In [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

the example is:

```
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

My question is whether --save-dev should be used in an application, because TypeScript is transpiled and not deployed? Some comments on the article mention similar, but there is no answer I could see.

Perhaps --save is useful in a library to drag around the types when others install your library?

Am I missing something else this is useful for and what is the best practice? Thanks.

Comment: yeah I have had the same thought, I think `save-dev` makes more sense

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From [Microsoft/types-publisher #81](https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81):

> Using --save-dev is fine when you're writing a simple application, and
>   it won't be used as a library. The problem comes along when you might
>   have dependencies. If you stored your type declarations in your
>   devDependencies, your consumers would not automatically get your type
>   declarations. They'd then have to manually add your declaration file
>   dependencies as their devDependencies.
>
> Given that breaking consumers is a worse problem than slightly-larger
>   packages, we've made --save the default in our documentation.